# javascript to show only part of elements with marked in one cell in datatable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Live html/js code https://jsfiddle.net/larrycai/9e8rg76f/2/ (data is sample, not real)

[image]

I have lots of 3pps for scanned container images, see column `3pp lists`, normally it could have 100+ 3pps.

In order to have better UX, I want

- it defaults to show 20 components (with `...`) in end inside the cell
- if something is searched in the search box, those filtered 3pps can be marked out ([datatables.mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js)? in the cell

  - if too many are marked, then show 20 components as maximum still
- it will be good to have more/less button as well, so if user want to expand the row, all the 3pps can be expanded.

I tried to use `render()` function, bit it seems if I filtered, then Datatable search can't cover all original 3pp list

```
   var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
     "data": jsonData,
     "columns": [{
         "data": "name"
       },
       {
         "data": "image",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
           return "" + data + "";
         }
       },
       {
         "data": "3pp",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
           /*
           1. if nothing in search (initial), show first SHOW_NUM keywords + ...
           2. if value in search, show matched 3pps, if it is bigger than 20, show first 20 keywords + ...
           */
           return data.slice(0, SHOW_NUM) + " ..."
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never understood why `render` replaces the data. Instead, use callback after the row has been rendered to amend the rendered cell using the data attribute. I've used [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) and [jQuery data cell click callback](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html), which passes the referenced row and data to a small `prettify3pp` function that quote `renders` unquote the cell with updated content.

Add a little few bootstrap badges and voila.

```js
var jsonData = [{
  "name": "ubuntu",
  "image": "ubuntu:focal",
  "3pp": ['acl:2.3.1-1', 'adduser:3.118ubuntu5', 'apt:2.4.8', 'attr:2.5.1-1build1', 'audit:3.0.7-1build1', 'base-files:12ubuntu4.2', 'base-passwd:3.5.52build1', 'bash:5.1-6ubuntu1', 'berkeleydb:5.3.28+dfsg1-0.8ubuntu3', 'bzip2:1.0.8-5build1', 'cdebconf:0.261ubuntu1', 'coreutils:8.32-4.1ubuntu1', 'dash:0.5.11+git20210903+057cd650a4ed-3build1', 'debconf:1.5.79ubuntu1', 'debianutils:5.5-1ubuntu2', 'diffutils:3.8-0ubuntu2', 'dpkg:1.21.1ubuntu2.1', 'e2fsprogs:1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1', 'findutils:4.8.0-1ubuntu3', 'gcc-12:12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04', 'glibc:2.35-0ubuntu3.1', 'gmp:6.2.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1', 'gnupg:2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1', 'gnutls:3.7.3-4ubuntu1.1', 'grep:3.7-1build1', 'gzip:1.10-4ubuntu4.1', 'hostname:3.23ubuntu2', 'iconv:2.35', 'init-system-helpers:1.62', 'kerberos:', 'keyutils:1.6.1-2ubuntu3', 'krb5:1.19.2-2', 'libcap:', 'libcap:2.44-1build3', 'libcap-ng:0.7.9-2.2build3', 'libffi:3.4.2-4', 'libgcrypt:1.9.4-3ubuntu3', 'libgpg-error:1.43-3', 'libidn2:2.3.2-2build1', 'libnsl:', 'libnsl:1.3.0-2build2', 'libseccomp:2.5.3-2ubuntu2', 'libsemanage:3.3-1build2', 'libsepol:3.3-1build1', 'libtasn1:4.18.0-4build1', 'libtasn1-6:4.18.0-4build1', 'libtirpc:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.1', 'libunistring:1.0-1', 'libxcrypt:4.4.27-1', 'linux-pam:1.4.0-11ubuntu2', 'lsb:11.1.0ubuntu4', 'lz4:1.9.3-2build2', 'mawk:1.3.4.20200120-3', 'ncurses:6.3-2', 'nettle:3.7.3-1build2', 'openssl:3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6', 'p11-kit:0.24.0-6build1', 'pcre:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1', 'pcre2:10.39-3ubuntu0.1', 'perl:5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1', 'procps:3.3.17-6ubuntu2', 'readline:', 'sed:4.8-1ubuntu2', 'selinux:3.3-1build2', 'sensible-utils:0.0.17', 'shadow:4.8.1-2ubuntu2', 'systemd:249.11-0ubuntu3.6', 'sysvinit:3.01-1ubuntu1', 'tar:1.34+dfsg-1build3', 'tdb:1.46.5', 'ubuntu-keyring:2021.03.26', 'usrmerge:25ubuntu2', 'util-linux:2.37.2-4ubuntu3', 'xxhash:0.8.1-1', 'xz:5.2.5-2ubuntu1', 'zlib:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2', 'zstd:1.4.8+dfsg-3build1'],
  "report": "report-581-20221104-154434.pdf"
}, {
  "name": "toolkit",
  "image": "ubuntu-tookit:jammy",
  "3pp": ['jfrog-jfrog-cli:', 'jfrog-jfrog-cli-core:v2.20.3', 'jfrog-jfrog-client-go:v1.21.0', 'jq:1.6-3.3.1', 'json-c:0.13-3.3.1', 'jszwec-csvutil:v1.7.1', 'jwalterweatherman:v1.1.0', 'kerberos:', 'kerberos:1.19', 'kevinburke-ssh_config:v0.0.0-20201106050909-4977a11b4351', 'keyutils:1.6.3-5.6.1', 'klauspost-compress:v1.13.5', 'kmod:29-4.15.1', 'less:530-3.3.2', 'libassuan:2.5.1-2.14', 'libatomic1:', 'libcap:', 'libcap:2.26-4.6.1', 'libcap-ng:0.7.9-4.37', 'libdevmapper:1.03.01', 'libedit:3.1.snap20150325-2.12', 'libfdisk:2.36.2', 'libffi:3.2.1.git259-10.8', 'libgcrypt:1.8.2-8.42.1', 'libgpg-error:1.29-1.8', 'libidn2:2.2.0-3.6.1', 'libksba:1.3.5-2.14', 'libmnl:1.0.4-1.25', 'libmpc3:1.1.0-1.47', 'libnsl:', 'libnsl:1.2.0-2.44', 'libproxy:0.4.15-12.41', 'libqrencode:4.0.0-1.17', 'libsanitizer:', 'libseccomp:', 'libsemanage:3.0-1.27', 'libsepol:3.0-1.31', 'libsolv:0.7.22', 'libssh:0.8.7-10.12.1', 'libtasn1:4.13-4.5.1', 'libtirpc:1.2.6-150300.3.3.1', 'libunistring:0.9.10-1.1', 'libusb:1.0.21-3.3.1', 'libxml2:2.9.7', 'linux-pam:', 'lua:5.3.6-3.6.1', 'lz4:1.9.2-3.3.1', 'make:4.2.1-7.3.2', 'manifoldco-promptui:v0.9.0', 'mergo:v0.3.12', 'minio-sha256-simd:v1.0.1-0.20210617151322-99e45fae3395', 'mitchellh-mapstructure:v1.5.0', 'mpfr:4.0.2-3.3.1', 'ncurses:6.1-5.9.1', 'nghttp2:1.40.0-6.1', 'npth:1.5-2.11', 'olekukonko-ts:v0.0.0-20171002115256-78ecb04241c0', 'oniguruma:6.7.0-1.19', 'openldap:', 'openslp:2.0.0-6.15.1', 'openssl:1.1.1d', 'owenrumney-go-sarif:v2.1.2', 'p11-kit:0.23.2-4.13.1', 'packaging:16.8', 'packaging:19.2', 'packaging:20.1', 'patch:2.7.6-3.5', 'pcre:8.45-20.10.1', 'pcre2:10.31-3.3.1', 'pep517:0.7.0', 'perl:5.26.1-150300.17.3.1', 'pgzip:v1.2.5', 'pierrec-lz4:v4.1.2', 'pinentry:1.1.0-4.3.1', 'pip:20.0.2', 'pkg-browser:v0.0.0-20210911075715-681adbf594b8', 'pkg-config:0.29.2-1.436', 'pkg-term:v1.1.0', 'popt:1.16-3.22', 'procps:3.3.15-7.22.1', 'properties:v1.8.6', 'protobuf:3.9.2-4.12.1', 'python:3.6.15-150300.10.21.1', 'rardecode:v1.1.0', 'readline:7.0', 'requests:2.22.0', 'rfkill:', 'rivo-uniseg:v0.2.0', 'rpm:4.14.3-150300.46.1', 'rsync:3.1.3-4.10.1', 'rubyist-tracerx:v0.0.0-20170927163412-787959303086', 'safestring:', 'sed:4.4-11.6', 'selinux:3.0-1.31', 'sergi-go-diff:v1.1.0', 'setuptools:44.1.1', 'shadow:', 'spew:v1.1.1', 'spf13-pflag:v1.0.3', 'spf13-pflag:v1.0.5', 'sqlite3:3.36.0-3.12.1', 'ssgelm-cookiejarparser:v1.0.1', 'sysfsutils:2.1.0-3.3.1', 'systemd:246.16-150300.7.45.1', 'tar:1.34-150000.3.12.1', 'testify:v1.5.1', 'testify:v1.8.0', 'ulikunitz-xz:v0.5.9', 'urfave-cli:v1.22.9', 'urllib3:1.25.7', 'util-linux:', 'util-linux:2.36.2', 'vbauerster-mpb:v7.4.2', 'vim:8.0.1568-5.17.1', 'viper:v1.12.0', 'visual_studio_runtime:', 'webencodings:0.5.1', 'wget:1.20.3-3.12.1', 'x-crypto:v0.0.0-20190426145343-a29dc8fdc734', 'x-crypto:v0.0.0-20220622213112-05595931fe9d', 'x-mod:v0.5.1', 'x-net:v0.0.0-20200301022130-244492dfa37a', 'x-net:v0.0.0-20220520000938-2e3eb7b945c2', 'x-sync:v0.0.0-20190911185100-cd5d95a43a6e', 'x-sys:v0.0.0-20200302150141-5c8b2ff67527', 'x-sys:v0.0.0-20220520151302-bc2c85ada10a', 'x-term:v0.0.0-20220526004731-065cf7ba2467', 'x-text:v0.3.0', 'x-text:v0.3.7', 'x-xerrors:v0.0.0-20220517211312-f3a8303e98df', 'xanzy-ssh-agent:v0.3.1', 'xi2-xz:v0.0.0-20171230120015-48954b6210f8', 'xo-terminfo:v0.0.0-20210125001918-ca9a967f8778', 'xxhash:', 'xz:5.2.3-150000.4.7.1', 'zlib:1.2.11-150000.3.30.1', 'zlib:1.2.3', 'zlib:1.2.5', 'zlib:1.2.8', 'zstd:1.4.4-1.6.1'],
  "report": "report-584-20221104-154434.pdf"
}];
var SHOW_NUM = 20
$(document).ready(function() {

  const prettify3pp = (row, data, searchTerm, showAll) => {
    let deps
    if (searchTerm === '') {
      deps = data['3pp'].map(dep => `<span class="badge bg-secondary">${dep}</span>`)
    } else {
      deps = data['3pp'].filter(dep => dep.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)).map(dep => `<span class="badge bg-primary">${dep}</span>`)
    }
    if (deps.length > SHOW_NUM && !showAll) {
      const totalLength = deps.length
      deps = deps.slice(0, SHOW_NUM)
      deps.push(`<span class="badge bg-info show-all">Showing ${deps.length} of ${totalLength} - Show all</span>`)
    }
    row.querySelector('td.shorten').innerHTML = deps.join('<span hidden>,</span> ')
  }
  const table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "data": jsonData,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "image",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<a href='https://hub.docker.com/_/" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "3pp",
        className: 'shorten',
      },
      {
        "data": "report",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<a href='" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>"
        }
      }
    ],
    "rowCallback": function(row, data) {
      const searchTerm = this.api().search().toLowerCase()
      //console.log('rowCallback', row, data, searchTerm)
      prettify3pp(row, data, searchTerm)
    }
  })

  $('#dataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.shorten .show-all', function() {
    const row = $(this).closest('tr')[0]
    const data = table.row(row).data()
    const searchTerm = table.search().toLowerCase()
    //console.log('clicked row', row, data, searchTerm)
    prettify3pp(row, data, searchTerm, true)
  });
});
```

```css
.show-all {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Filter the 3pps: </h2>
  <table id="dataTable" class="datatables-table table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>container image</th>
        <th>3pp lists</th>
        <th>PDF</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly what I want, thx. I will try to understand the code, the `prettify3pp` is bonus for me